# Why are data migrations being moved to the command line for ASP.NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-migration, entity-framework-core

Previously you could just use the package manager console inside of VS. But now all the examples are using command line tools outside of VS. Like this:

http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Note that there has always been a command line tool for running migration pre EF7.  Take a look inside the tools folder of the Entity Framework nuget package.  More specifically, this would be to support platforms other than Windows?

Comment: To me,the Package Manager Console always seemed like a *really* odd place to run those commands from in the first place.  I mean, its name is "Package Manager", it's designed to manage and install source code level project library packages, why would you run a command from there to migrate data?

Comment: I just never likes the DOS command line and having to navigate to deep in the C drive and type things out.. With the package manager console I was already in the right place... Why not create a GUI for the common code migration commands ? Rt click the project and 'update migrations' or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NuGet commands will eventually work (see issue [#978](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/978)), but they need some features to be implemented by the NuGet and Web Tools teams first.